# Rewriting very old commits in git

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-rewrite-history

I have to rewrite very old commits in the git repository and not sure if it's even possible. By rewriting I mean squashing and rewording some commits. It's also worth mentioning that there are lots of merge commits in the repository and most of them should stay.

So let's say my repo is `A <- B <- C <- D <- E <- ... X <- Y <- Z` and I have to squash `A` and `B` and reword `C` and `D`.

Well, I created a new branch `tmp` and have done the following things:

1. My `tmp` branch references to the `D` commit.
2. I made a squash and reword for required commits.
3. Now in the `tmp` branch I have smth like this - `A' <- C' <- D'`. By the way, it's actually fine that rebase ignores all the merge commits before `D`, but merge commits after `D` must stay.

And now I want to merge somehow my `tmp` branch and `master` branch to get something like this: `A' <- C' <- D' <- E <- ... <- X <- Y <- Z` with all merge commits starting from `E`. For me, it looks like changing a parent for commit `E`, but not sure if it's possible to do this. There is probably some other ways to achieve what I need.

**UPDATE**

I tried to make a `git replace D D'` on the `master` branch and after this `git filter-branch -- tmp` and it almost worked. Unfortunately, when I executed replace some commands after `D` moved to the bottom and the history looked like `A <- E <- F <- A' <- C' <- D' <- G <- ... <- X <- Y <- Z` and it was very strange to me, but when I tried `git replace C D'` everything worked fine except duplicated `D` and `D'` commits. Not sure if this is a good approach, but look like the only one in my case.

I'm sorry if it's confusing, I'll try to clarify if something is unclear.

Comment: "For me, it looks like changing a parent for commit `E`" : this won't ever happen. If its parent changes, it won't be `E` anymore, but another commit `E'`. **Every** commit further down the history will have to change to reflect the new ancestry. You could do a few searches here around `filter-branch`, but be aware that this is pretty heavy, and even more on numerous (and old) commits.

Comment: I guess you can do an interactive rebase all the way to `A`. But as @RomainValeri mentioned, this will also change every commit.

Comment: @mnestorov, yes, but there are lots of commits and in addition, I have to save some merge commits, but with rebase it's quite difficult to do as I know.

Comment: @RomainValeri thanks, I will do.

Comment: `filter-branch` is the right tool.  Contrary to comments above, this is not a particularly heavy-weight operation - git can handle this pretty efficiently even for large histories.  However, it *is* a major history rewrite, which has costs for the team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `git filter-branch` with `parent-filter` to "re-parent" `E`.  The docs, including examples to do just the sort of thing you want to do, are here:

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch

As always, the commit `E` itself cannot be changed; really you are creating `E'` which has parent of `D'`, and so on down the tree until you get `X'`, `Y'`, `Z'`.  However, because you're accepting the commits' content "as is" rather than re-applying patches the way rebase does, this works fine for any commit graph (whereas it's not very hard to create a repo where `rebase` will do the wrong thing with merge commits, even when told to preserve merges).

(The reason you normally rebase instead of reparenting like this, is that you generally can't assume the new base has the same content as the old base.  But in this case it sounds like you can; only the commit graph leading up to `D'` differs from `D`, not the content.)

The important thing to remember is that you are rewriting history, which will break all existing clones of the repo.  For something this sweeping, the safest thing is to:

1. Let everyone know a rewrite is coming, and give them a cut-off date.  Tell them that all changes must be pushed (not necessarily merged) to the remote by the cut-off, and that as of the cut-off they must discard their local clones.
2. After the cut-off time, do the rewrite, and replace the origin repo with the result.
3. Once you give the all-clear, everyone re-clones from the new origin.